# NGINX reverse proxy with multiple end points on same port same server

Tags: nginx, iis, load-balancing

I have multiple Virtual directories hosted in IIS, with name as **Service.1.api Service.2.api Service.3.api** and so on.

Which can be accessed using

```
 http://192.168.0.1/Service.1.api
 http://192.168.0.1/Service.2.api
 http://192.168.0.1/Service.3.api
```

and also I have domain https://example.com which need to pointed to these api with nginx load balancing

for example my client will be calling https://example.com/api/getUser which need to load balanced to

```
 http://192.168.0.1/Service.1.api/getUser
 http://192.168.0.1/Service.2.api/getUser
 http://192.168.0.1/Service.3.api/getUser
```

I know load balancing can be done in nginx using different ip/port using reverse proxy for the same end points of request and internal servers, but here request end point is common and internal server end points are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite urls in `nginx`
https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

> If the specified regular expression matches a request URI, URI is
>   changed as specified in the replacement string. The rewrite directives
>   are executed sequentially in order of their appearance in the
>   configuration file.

So after you [proxy_pass](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) the request the modified URL will come to the IIS server